# Having trouble updating JSON File in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON File below content.

```html
{
  "properties": {
    "workspaceId": "xxxx",
    "logs": [
      {
        "categoryGroup": "allLogs",
        "enabled": false,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "enabled": false,
          "days": 0
        }
      }
    ],
    "logAnalyticsDestinationType": ""
  }
}
```

I am trying to change the value of the object **workspaceId** from "xxxx" to actual value from a string LAWorkspaceID. I am using below code but getting error

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
> RAMP-VinnyLearn. Newtonsoft.Json: Accessed JObject values with invalid key value: 0. Object property name expected.

```html
string LAWorkSpaceID = "NewValueForMyLAWorkspaceID";
string json = File.ReadAllText("DisableRequestBody.json");
dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
jsonObj["properties"][0]["workspaceId"] = LAWorkSpaceID;
string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText("DisableRequestBody.json", output);
```

Comment: `"properties"` clearly describes a JSON _object_, not a JSON _array_.  Why are you writing `jsonObj["properties"][0]["workspaceId"]` instead of `jsonObj["properties"]["workspaceId"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"properties" is an object and not array.

try to replace

```
jsonObj["properties"][0]["workspaceId"]
```

with

```
jsonObj["properties"]["workspaceId"]
```

and the output is

```
{
  "properties": {
    "workspaceId": "NewValueForMyLAWorkspaceID",
    "logs": [
      {
        "categoryGroup": "allLogs",
        "enabled": false,
        "retentionPolicy": {
          "enabled": false,
          "days": 0
        }
      }
    ],
    "logAnalyticsDestinationType": ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dynamic type then you can use the following approach too:

```
string LAWorkSpaceID = "NewValueForMyLAWorkspaceID";
string json = File.ReadAllText("DisableRequestBody.json");
dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

Console.WriteLine(jsonObj.properties.workspaceId);
Console.WriteLine(jsonObj.properties.logs[0].categoryGroup);
Console.WriteLine(jsonObj.properties.logs[0].retentionPolicy.enabled);
```

Assuming your JSON data is:

```
"properties": {
"workspaceId": "NewValueForMyLAWorkspaceID",
"logs": [
  {
    "categoryGroup": "allLogs",
    "enabled": false,
    "retentionPolicy": {
      "enabled": false,
      "days": 0
    }
  }
],
"logAnalyticsDestinationType": ""
 }
}
```

Output:

[image: Output Console]